# MySQL index is not used when certain columns are returned

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

I have a table with a `created_on` field that is indexed by itself. When looking at a slow query I realized that depending on what column I return the index is not used. In the following two examples I have the `foo` and `bar` columns.

- `foo` is part of another index with three other columns.
- `bar` is not indexed at all.

---

```
EXPLAIN SELECT created_on, foo FROM T1
WHERE created_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

No index used, +3 mil rows are searched. (`Using where`)

If I add a `LIMIT` clause it *will* use the index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT created_on, foo FROM T1
WHERE created_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
LIMIT 1000;
```

---

If using another column `bar` it will also use the index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT created_on, bar FROM T1
WHERE created_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

Index is used and only 1.5 mil rows are searched. (`Using where; Using index`)

Why does MySQL skip the index for one of these queries?

Comment: The question is why an index would be used if half the rows match the filtering conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, I do not understand. The only difference between the queries is whether I return the additional column `A` or `B`. Why does that change the use of the index to _filter_ the results (the WHERE clause)?

Comment: . . Indexes are normally used to *reduce* the number of data pages being read.  From what you describe, this is not happening with your query, so it is surprising that a non-covering index is being used under any circumstance.  One exception would be a clustered index, but then I would expect it to always be used.

Answer (score 2):

"Using index" in the `Extra` column of `EXPLAIN` output means that the query was satisfied from a *covering index*, with no need to lookup data pages in the underlying table.

For the first query, this means that MySQL used an index that contained *all* of the columns from `T1` referenced in the query, i.e. both `foo` and `created_on`.

(No indication given if `created_on` is the leading column in the index, allowing MySQL to  use a range scan operation to quickly eliminate boatloads of rows, or whether MySQL is checking every entry in the index, doing a full index scan. We would need to look more closely at other columns in the `EXPLAIN` output.)

---

With the `EXPLAIN` shown for the second query (no "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output), we deduce that there is no index that contains both `bar` and `created_on`.

So MySQL is going to have to access pages in the underlying tables, to get the values for some of those columns.

Now it's a matter of whether it's going to be less expensive (faster) to make use of an index to narrow down the rows that need to be looked at, or faster to just scan the whole table.

---

Typically, when we say that MySQL "uses an index", we aren't referring to a *covering index*. We are typically referring to a **range** scan operation or **ref** lookup operation.  We are typically saying that MySQL is making effective use of an index significantly reduce the number or rows that need to be checked; quickly narrowing in on the rows that are needed, by very efficiently eliminating vast swaths of rows that do not need to be inspected.

To identify whether an index is being used, we look at the `key`,`keylen` and `ref` columns in the EXPLAIN output.  (When "Using index" is absent from the `Extra` column, that does not mean that MySQL is *not* "using an index".)

---

To more directly answer the question that was asked:

**Q:** *Why does MySQL skip the index for one of these queries?*

**A:** MySQL optimizer will choose an execution plan that makes use of an index when it determines that a suitable index is available, and when the execution plan using an index is the lowest estimated cost out of all plans it considered. It's possible that the optimizer will determine that a plan not using an index has a lower estimated cost.

Adding a suitable index can tremendously impact SQL performance, by making more efficient operations available to the optimizer.

And given the performance improvements we can conjure by adding a suitable index, its understandable that our knee-jerk reaction to poor performance is to "add an index".

But adding an index is not the "silver bullet". We need to be careful to use SQL constructs that don't disable MySQL ability to use an index, and we also need to carefully consider which indexes are optimal, not just for a single statement, but also considering the entire SQL workload.

This answer just barely grazes the topic of MySQL "using an index."

For completeness we should also note (at a risk of unnecessarily muddying the water too much) that the behavior of the MySQL optimizer is influenced by available statistics, the setting of some system variables (`optimizer_switch` in particular) as well as optimizer "hints" included in the SQL text.

Comment: `created_on` is not a composite index. It is indexed by itself. Neither `foo` nor `bar` are in an index with `created_on`.

Comment: MySQL will only show "Using index" when it uses a *covering* an index that contains all of the columns referenced in the query.

Comment: The excerpts of the EXPLAIN output provided in the question are insufficient for us to determine whether an index is being used, and *which* index is being used, and whether its a full scan of the index, or a range scan operation with the leading `created_on` column.  (The question says that for one of the queries "the" index is used; but the question also indicates there is more than one index.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT created_on, foo FROM T1
WHERE created_on > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY;
```

The Optimizer might, or might not, use `INDEX(created_on)`.  It depends on what percentage of the table is rows created in the last 5 days.  A small percentage (under, say, 20%), the index will be used.

On the other hand, `INDEX(created_on, foo)` (in this order) since it will be "covering".

> foo is part of another index with three other columns.

The order of the columns in the index is *very* important.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need further discussion.

> if using another column bar it will also use the index.

That index *may* be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you need further discussion.

> (Using where; Using index)

"Using index" means that *all* the necessary columns are in the index.  Hence, only the index's BTree need be looked at.  Each secondary index implicitly includes the `PRIMARY KEY` columns in it.  So, I infer that you have `INDEX(bar)` *and* `created_at` is somewhere in the `PRIMARY KEY`.

> Why does MySQL skip the index for one of these queries?

The Optimizer asks which would be faster (and *usually* comes up with the correct answer):

- The index is "covering", so let's use only the index.
- Let's use the index, but bounce between it an the data's BTree to get some other columns.
- I can't do much with the `WHERE`, but I can use an index for the `ORDER BY`; let's do that, and hope that I don't have to scan too many rows.
- Punt.  Let's ignore all the indexes and simply scan the data, tossing any rows that don't match the `WHERE` clause.

Yes, that last option is often the fastest.  Some possible characteristics:

- No secondary index helps much with the `WHERE`.
- There is a `WHERE`, but it does not eliminate many rows.
- No `ORDER BY`, or no index matches it.
- No `LIMIT`.

If using MySQL, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` will provide the "cost based" calculations it did to make the decision.

My [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) helps with building optimal indexes.

Comment: Excellent synopsis. There's enough info provided here to help lead to a comprehension of the role of the MySQL optimizer, and a rudimentary understanding of some of the operations available to it. +10

Comment: You said `A small percentage (under, say, 20%), the index will be used.`. How did you get the number?

Comment: @Manuel - Experience (both mine and others).  One user experimented until he found the exact cutoff of 31.2% for his million-row table.  The Optimizer uses a "cost-based analysis", which depends on many things.  I find "about xx%" to be something that the programmer can understand and possibly use.

Comment: I was looking for that cost-based number in the mysql docs, but I couldn't find it. I'd rather have a mysql-documented number (that may be even configurable?), than a empirical found number. Do you have any links?

Comment: @Manuel - I have mostly heard about "cost-based optimization" from developers at conferences.  It's rather low level and complex; I don't have any links.  As for my "20%", that's an empirically found number from hundreds of random experiments, most not 'scientific'.  When 10% of the rows are needed, it _usually_ uses an index; at 30%, it _rarely_ uses the index.  Since it is based on statistics, _sometimes_ `ANALYZE TABLE` will cause it to flip to the other side of that boundary.